# how do i allign my div containers using css

Tags: php, html, css

how can i align my containers horizontally inside another container. also i want to center align them when the window is resized because every time i try it the containers just keep on popping somewhere i don't want them to please help me thank you. below is the code:

my index page

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Kwiktable </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jssor.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="headercontainer" style="z-index:1000;">
  <div class="header clearfix"> <span class="logo"><img src="img/kwiktable.png"><a href = "index.php">&nbsp <img src = "img/kwik.png"> </a></span>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" style="color:#888;" 
    value="Search" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)">
    <script>
        =function inputFocus(i){
    if(i.value==i.defaultValue){ i.value=""; i.style.color="#000"; }
        }
    function inputBlur(i){
    if(i.value==""){ i.value=i.defaultValue; i.style.color="#888"; }
        }
    </script>
    <div class="nav">
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
      <label for="toggle" class="toggle" onclick=""></label>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="current" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserve.php">Reservations</a></li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Log in</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<center>
<br>    <br>    <br>    <br>
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:100%;max-width:1050px;background-color:#E8E8E8;overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid #000000;">
<div class="container" style=" margin-left: 10px; width 100%; max-width: 450px; background-color:#E8E8E8;overflow:hidden;">
  <?php include 'content1.html';?>
  <?php include 'content.html'; ?>
</div>
<div class="container1" style="margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 10px; width 100%; max-width: 450px; background-color:#E8E8E8;overflow:hidden; "> </div>
<div  class="container2">
  <?php 
    echo "<br><h1>Kwiktable's Best</h1>";
    include 'best.php';
    ?>
  <br>      <br>      <br>      <br>
</div>
</center>
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

my css file:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}

body, a {
    font: normal 16px Helvetica, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    color: #3f3f3f
}

.textbox {
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FFEAEA;
    border: solid 1px #646464;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px 2px;
}

.textbox:hover {
    background-color: #F7C4C4;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
    -o-transition: all .25s linear;
    transition: all .25s linear
}

.textbox:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
    -o-transition: all .25s linear;
    transition: all .25s linear
}

iframe {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.headercontainer {
    opacity: 0.95;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(img/menubar.jpg);
    background-color: #D93625;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #888888;
}

.headercontainer:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both
}

.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 0 0;
    background: #bbbfbf;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid #51c1f1
}
 @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

.copyright { display: none }
}

body {
    -webkit-animation: bugfix infinite 1s;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
}
 @-webkit-keyframes 
bugfix {  from {
 padding:0;
}

to { padding: 0; }
}

.header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#toggle, .toggle { display: none }

.menu>li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: ""
}

.clearfix:after { clear: both }
 @media only screen and (max-width:768px) {

.textbox {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0
}

.menu>li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0
}

.menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.toggle {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    margin-top: 8px
}

#toggle:checked~.menu {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1
}
}

.header {
    min-height: 80px;
    max-width: 1500px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background: #D93625;
    color: #fff;
}

.header>.logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 50px
}

.nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    text-align: right
}

.nav, .menu, .menu>li, .menu>li>a { height: 100% }

.menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 2.8;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
    -o-transition: all .25s linear;
    transition: all .25s linear
}

.menu>li>a:hover, .menu>li>a:focus {
    background: #8B0000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #8B0000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #3D0000 inset;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #FF9292;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #E6FF00;
}

.menu>li>a.current {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900
}

.toggle { z-index: 2 }
 @media only screen and (max-width:820px) {

.textbox {
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.menu {
    background: #363636;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu, .menu>li, .menu>li>a { height: auto }

.menu>li>a {
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #363636;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

.menu>li>a:hover, .menu>li>a:focus {
    background: #D70000;
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 25px;
}

.toggle:after {
    content: 'Menu';
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #3D0000 inset;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #E6FF00;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0 0;
    margin-top: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #D70000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -o-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.toggle:hover:after { background: #920000 }

h1 {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
}

.container {
    width: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#toggle:checked+.toggle:after { content: 'Close' }
}

.share-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-image: url(img/share/share-icons.png)
}
```

Comment: A **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)** will be great!

Comment: i would also think so, although the code includes other php's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing `</div>` tag which is more than likely why it's jumping all over the page. Use a tool like this to help you: http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

Nice going with the responsive design, but you may want t focus more on your HTML and CSS.

`<center>` tags are a bad hack. You should be doing that with CSS. Additionally, your use of `<br>`s for spacing should also be done with CSS. Take a look into padding and margin.

If you wanted to `<center>` a div, the css alternative is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 800px;">This will be centered </div>
</div>
```

Just to start you out.

What happens here is the container div fills 100% as a standard div should. The child div (the one with the style tag) sets its top and bottom margin to 0, and its left and right margin to auto. The important part here is that the div also has a fixed width. So the div will take up 800px in this instance an any remaining space will `auto`matically be distributed evenly by the margin.

You could Google this and get a better explanation I'm sure.

Comment: hey thanks! I added <center> and <br> because its much easier to see things in my own perspective. but anyways thanks for answering

Comment: did you remember to add that missing `</div>` tag? Run your code through that validator I linked again.

Comment: my code before for css on my container1 and container, they have float:left or float right if the window size is full but when i resize the window they stick to their places and leaves spaces on their sides. they are not centered.

Comment: i've added the div but i think its not quite it. although they are now aligned. they are aligned to the left